# Docker agent in Jenkinsfile correct syntax and command not found error in the output log

Tags: java, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I checked the other posts but they are not what my issue represents.
I'm doing the Linuxacademy "Certified Jenkins Engineer" course and at the "Functional Testing" lesson, we add a docker agent with some steps in the Jenkinsfile but I am confused about the syntax used vs the syntax described in the official Jenkins Pipeline documentation [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).
What the Jenkins tries to achieve is to run a test on a.jar file on a Jenkins node with CentOS but the test needs to be run on a Debian OS, in order to do that on the CentOS node, the Jenkinsfile has a stage with a Docker agent and a commmand that  pulls the openjdk image from Dockerhub and run some command in it.
This is the syntax from the [Lesson Repo](https://github.com/linuxacademy/content-jenkins-java-project/blob/master/Jenkinsfile):

```
stage("Test on Debian") {
  agent {
    docker 'openjdk:8u121-jre'
  }
  steps {
    sh "wget http://brandon4231.mylabserver.com/rectangles/all/rectangle_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.jar"
    sh "java -jar rectangle_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.jar 3 4"
```

Note that I simplified the file to match the work in progress, this one is the final version, but the focus is on the agent line. 
My first question is that the Jenkins documentation syntax is different from the one used here but in the lesson video it runs with no issues, the correct syntax should be `agent {
        docker { image 'openjdk:8u121-jre' }
    }`
My second question is, wheter I use one or the other syntax, and also I used the openjdk:7u181-jre because the one from the lesson is not longer available, I get this error in the console log output:
[image]

If go to the node terminal and manually run

> docker run openjdk:7u181-jre
>   it works fine, I run it as not sudo user.

Also I don't understand what the docker command does in the Jenkinsfile: Does it run the container after pulling it or just pull the container?

Any idea about what's going on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please install docker in the Jenkins server.

2) Please change the user-mode of Jenkins and docker same by running below command and restart both Jenkins and docker and now u will be able to access.

> sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins-server-user-name
>
> sudo systemctl restart docker
>
> sudo systemctl restart jenkins

To install Jenkins: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-16-04

To install Docker: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04

*Note: Verified on ubuntu server*